# Using Geogebra to export geometries

Tags: import

I made a drawing using Geogebra as shown in the figure below:

[image]

And I export a TEX file from it:

```
\documentclass[0pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \draw (-6.398243018635849,29.30976776220647)-- (86.80087849068208,49.65488388110324);
    \draw (97.54228504819193,22.03412416179222)-- (15.084570096383837,-25.93175167641558);
    \draw [shift={(0,0)}] plot[domain=1.7857219540430334:5.239245930761878,variable=\t]({1*30*cos(\t r)+0*30*sin(\t r)},{0*30*cos(\t r)+1*30*sin(\t r)});
    \draw [shift={(90,35)}] plot[domain=-1.0439393764177076:1.785721954043033,variable=\t]({1*15*cos(\t r)+0*15*sin(\t r)},{0*15*cos(\t r)+1*15*sin(\t r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think I'm exporting with wrong units so the drawing does not fit on the sheet:

Should I correct something in Geogebra before exporting or is it more interesting to correct the obtained code?

**EDIT**

Based on the comment from [marsupilam](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380040/using-geogebra-to-export-geometries#comment940807_380040). How can I make the design centered on the sheet and with a width of 70mm?

Comment: Just add the option `scale=0.7` *(or some other factor)* in the `\begin{tikzpicture}[...]` to reduce the size by `30 %`, and remove the `x=1cm, y=1cm` options.

Comment: Based on your edit: Maybe using the `standalone` package for the figure and then including it as PDF with `\includegraphics[width=70mm]{myFile}` could be an option.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh That would be the way I'd do it. Ideally, the tikzpicture should be scaled empirically beforehand to be close to the desired width (70mm), so the includegraphics rescaling does not modify the width of lines in the pic too much.

Comment: In the past GEOGEBRA exported terrible `tikz` files, by the way

Comment: Always remove the `\clip` line that is usually completely wrong.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It is not too bad as a general rule, for simple drawings, except for the ridiculous float precision, in this case. What geogebra does terribly is exporting function graphs, hardcoding the axes and sometimes exporting the curve as a very very long series of `\draw (.,.) -- (.,.);`, with repeated color options...

Comment: I thought of drawing the actual scale of what I need to avoid errors and can export reduced. The SCALE option was very interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really your question, but it is also fun to draw this in tikz...

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=39, scale=4]

  % parameters of the shape
  \def\thet{75}
  \def\r{.4}

  \coordinate (O) at (0,0) ;
  \coordinate (a1) at ({cos(\thet)},{sin(\thet)});
  \coordinate (a2) at ({cos(\thet)},{-sin(\thet)});
  \coordinate (vanish) at ({sec(\thet)},0);

  \path  (vanish) -- (a1) coordinate[pos=\r] (b1) 
         (vanish) -- (a2) coordinate[pos=\r] (b2) 
         (vanish) -- (O)  coordinate[pos=\r] (o) ;

 \pgfresetboundingbox

  \draw [blue, very thick, fill=red!20] (a1) 
    arc [start angle=\thet,end angle=360-\thet,radius=1] -- (b2) 
    arc [start angle=-\thet,end angle=\thet,radius=\r] -- cycle ; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted ... Using parameters to draw this cam. You understood my question without mentioning ... I need to improve my question ... Sorry for the others who helped ...

Comment: I'm new and I do not know how to ask. I do not know the resources of the TEX world. That's why I'm using Geogebra in my first steps.

Comment: @LCarvalho Thank you. By curiosity, what is this shape called for cams ? It is also the shape of a simple 2 pulley-belt transmission, but I don't know the name (partial cone on a circle ?)

Comment: See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126796/37895)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cam

Answer (score 4):

You could calculate the value for `x` by looking at the clipped rectangle on the assumption that this is the area you want to see generally.

(In this particular case the clipping is not necessary, because nothing drawn is outside of the clipped rectangle. So you could also have a look at the outer coordinates of your drawn shape).

x = 70mm / (175.88229072982594 - (-92.2298265729806)) = 0.26mm

To preserve the axial ratio you should set y = x.
Then you get this result (I added the red rectangle, to see the clipped area):

```
\documentclass[0pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.26mm,y=0.26mm]
    \clip(-92.2298265729806,-92.52338090781379) rectangle (175.88229072982594,94.97188107843031);
    \draw[red] (-92.2298265729806,-92.52338090781379) rectangle (175.88229072982594,94.97188107843031);
    \draw (-6.398243018635849,29.30976776220647)-- (86.80087849068208,49.65488388110324);
    \draw (97.54228504819193,22.03412416179222)-- (15.084570096383837,-25.93175167641558);
    \draw [shift={(0,0)}] plot[domain=1.7857219540430334:5.239245930761878,variable=\t]({1*30*cos(\t r)+0*30*sin(\t r)},{0*30*cos(\t r)+1*30*sin(\t r)});
    \draw [shift={(90,35)}] plot[domain=-1.0439393764177076:1.785721954043033,variable=\t]({1*15*cos(\t r)+0*15*sin(\t r)},{0*15*cos(\t r)+1*15*sin(\t r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could delete the line with \ clip ... and \ draw [red] ..... These lines that were obtained by the export are [unnecessary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380040/using-geogebra-to-export-geometries#comment940818_380040). Excuse me.

Comment: Alright, I edited the answer.